# xUnit test fails while comparing Lists

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, linq-to-entities, xunit

Here is my unit test and it fails with a message.
Kindly help me fix this.

Update Question:

It looks like i am trying to unit test the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` method. So is this a legitimate unit test?

Message:

```
    Expected got to be equal to {
    JsonFromTo.CMSContacts.ContactsFilter
    {
        cms = "asees", 
        groups = {"jio", "jiso"}
    }, 
    JsonFromTo.CMSContacts.ContactsFilter
    {
        cms = "bsees", 
        groups = {"jto"}
    }
}
, but {
    JsonFromTo.CMSContacts.ContactsFilter
    {
        cms = "asees", 
        groups = {"jio", "jiso"}
    }, 
    JsonFromTo.CMSContacts.ContactsFilter
    {
        cms = "bsees", 
        groups = {"jto"}
    }
}
 differs at index 0.
```

System Under Test:

```
public IEnumerable<ContactsFilter> GetFilters(string json)
{
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ContactsFilter>>(json);
}

public class ContactsFilter
{
    public string cms { get; set; }
    public List<string> groups { get; set; }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
public class CmsContactsTest
{
    public const string Filters = @"[{""cms"": ""asees"",""groups"": [""jio"",""jiso""]},{""cms"": ""bsees"",""groups"": [""jto""]}]";

    [Fact]
    public void Should_Return_List()
    {
        //arrange
        var want = new List<ContactsFilter>()
        {
            new ContactsFilter()
            {
                cms = "asees",
                groups = new List<string>{ "jio", "jiso" }
            },
            new ContactsFilter()
            {
                cms = "bsees",
                groups = new List<string>{ "jto"}
            }
        };

        var got = new CmsContacts().GetFilters(Filters);
        got.Should().Equal(want);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says the difference is at index 0 so there may be some whitespace at the start of one the strings

Comment: @YungDeiza I don't think so

Comment: `Equal` uses `System.Object.Equals(System.Object)` you should move to `BeEquivalentTo`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to use [BeEquivalentTo](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/)

```cs
got.Should().BeEquivalentTo(want);
```

Quoting `BeEquivalentTo` source code:

```
    // Summary:
    //     Asserts that a collection of objects is equivalent to another collection of objects.        
    // ...
    // Remarks:
    //     Objects within the collections are equivalent when both object graphs have equally
    //     named properties with the same value, irrespective of the type of those objects.
    //     Two properties are also equal if one type can be converted to another and the
    //     result is equal. The type of a collection property is ignored as long as the
    //     collection implements System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 and all items
    //     in the collection are structurally equal. Notice that actual behavior is determined
    //     by the global defaults managed by FluentAssertions.AssertionOptions.
```

With `Equal`, elements are compared using their `System.Object.Equals(System.Object)`

Comment: by the way, it looks like i am indeed trying to unit test the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` method. is this a legitimate unit test?

Comment: Obviously was a nonsense test. I guess it was just a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).